# Is it possible to git without master?

Tags: git, github, linux-kernel

Good morning.
I want to manage my embedded linux kernel with git.
The git model is http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.

In Embedded Linux Kernel, every kernel version provided by the manufacturer is different.
A: 3.8
B: 3.10
C: 3.12

At first I tried to manage the kernel from git as shown below.

```
url.com/A/3.8_kernel.git
url.com/B/3.10_kernel.git
url.com/A/3.12_kernel.git
```

I kept thinking about how to manage the kernel from a single kernel.git repository.

```
url.com/kernel.git
```

There is a branch called A_3.8, B_3.10, and C_3.12 in kernel.git.
In this case, i do not need a master in kernel.git.
Is it possible to use git without a master in the same case?

I am a beginner of git.

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Master and branch makes no difference for git.
So you can use git without a master.

delete local master:

```
git checkout other_branch
git branch -D master
```

delete remote master:

```
git push origin :master
```

PS:
if you use github or gitlab manage git.You should set project default branch to other_branch(default is master) before delete remote master.